# Is there a Check out/in option for SharePoint 2003?

Tags: 2003

I have been asked to find out if there is the check in/out option for SharePoint 2003? If not, is there an add-on for this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use check in/out for documents in SharePoint 2003. Please check the following Microsoft article:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287876(v=office.12).aspx